# `object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js

I am using NextJS and I previously called an internal `/api` route to get this data using `fetch()`, however, I realized that for production, it won't let you use internal api calls inside `getServerSideProps` Therefore, I am trying to call my MongoDB database directly from `getServerSideProps`.

My problem is that I get the error that my `posts` data that I am passing as `props` isn't serializable: "*object ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types."*

I don't understand why, as it is in the form of: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], etc.` which should work when it's passed?

My code is below for reference (explanations below the code):

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    let returnID = null
    let posts = []
    let error = false
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(`mongodb+srv://MYUNIQUEMONDODBCONNECTIONDATA`);
        const db = client.db();
        const postsCollection = db.collection("posts");
        const result = await postsCollection.find({}).limit(10).toArray();
        console.log("RESULT: " + result)
        client.close();
        posts = result.map(r => {
            return {
                title: r.title,
                body: r.body,
                id: r._id,
            }
        });
        if (posts[posts.length - 1]?.id) { // make sure it's not undefined
            returnID = posts[posts.length - 1]?.id;
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        error = true
    }
    return {
        props: {
            startingID: String(returnID),
            startingError: error,
            startingPosts: posts,
        }
    }
}
```

My data I receive from my database is roughly as follows: `[{"title":"1","body":"1","id":"6276767ca21167f5043d3dc8"},{"title":"2","body":"2","id":"6276767fa21167f5043d3dc9"},{"title":"3","body":"3","id":"62767682a21167f5043d3dca"}, etc.]` Doesn't this match the format of my `posts` I'm passing as props?

The line `console.log("RESULT: " + result)` prints: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], etc.`

ANSWER from @jabaa: change the return to this line: `startingPosts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts))`

Comment: Have you done any additional debugging yet? Like console.log(actual data here)?

Comment: Yes, it all seems to check out, until it actually runs through the props and the error crops up.

Comment: What is `data`? Why do you overwrite `posts`?

Comment: @jabaa Apologies, I forgot to edit `data` out when I posted, it was from a previous attempt. I tried lots of things.

Comment: Can you serialize and los the return value?

Comment: @jabaa I am trying to serialize, so I can return my value `posts` through `props` as `props.startingPosts`

Comment: Where and how are you trying to serialize?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just need to in order to make the error go away; how: any method will be fine, where: somewhere that allows me to alter my `posts` list before it is returned

Comment: `if (posts[posts.length - 1]?.returnID` There is no returnID field inside post object. You return `title, body and id` fields from map. Shouldn't this be `if (posts[posts.length - 1]?.id`

Comment: @Inder, I just fixed both of those, good catch, I still get the same error though

Comment: Try this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11993#issuecomment-879857441

Comment: @Inder That solved it!! Thanks!, I've edited my question to reflect the answer

Comment: This is the "offical" way; using lean() to remove functions and the like from the returned mongo documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return {
        props: {
            startingID: String(returnID),
            startingError: error,
            startingPosts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)),
        }
    }
```

or As Chris mentioned you can use `.lean()` method.

Comment: .lean() doesn't fix the error for me, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)) does though. But seems like a weird hack, isn't there a more "proper" way to fix it?

Comment: @Julius Currently I was able to find only 2 solutions. If lean is not working then for now you'll have to stick to this parse and stringify method