# NextJS shallow routing breaks anchor tags

Tags: next.js

In a next.js app, I have a card detail page that takes `[id]` as a parameter. By design, if an invalid `id` is passed (e.g. `/card/pick-a-new-card`), then `getServerSideProps` picks a random card instead. [As suggested in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing), I'm using shallow routing to then update the URL:

```js
    // /card/[id].tsx
    useEffect(() => {
        router.push(`/card/${card?.id}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
    });
```

This works just fine. *Except* that it breaks my home button, which is rendered very plainly by:

```
   <Button color="inherit" href="/">Home</Button>
```

Now this home button no longer works -- nothing appears to happen after one clicks it.

For now, I've worked around the issue with the old school solution of

```js
   window.history.pushState(null, '', `/card/${card?.id}`);
```

But I have no idea what about the shallow route is killing the home button -- that behavior seems very concerning to me.

So far, I have tried these things with no change in behavior:

- using `<Link>` instead of a button.
- using a navigation script in `onClick` instead of a simple href.

Here's the complete `id.tsx` page:

```
import { Card, Deck } from '@prisma/client';
import type { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { MyAppBar } from '../../components/MyAppBar';
import { prisma } from '../../lib/prisma';
import { Button, Card as MuiCard, CardActions, CardContent, Container, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useAlert from '../../components/useAlert';
import { formatLastUsedDate } from '../../lib/utils';

const CardPage: NextPage<{ card: Card | null, deck: Deck }> = ({ card, deck }) => {

    const router = useRouter();
    const { setAlert } = useAlert();

    // update the URL
    useEffect(() => {
        // TODO: shallow routing sometimes kills all link navigation
        // router.push(`/card/${card?.id}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
        window.history.pushState(null, '', `/card/${card?.id}`);
    });

    // disable the button if it's just been clicked
    const [justClicked, setJustClicked] = useState(false);

    const refreshData = () => {
        router.replace(router.asPath)
    }

    async function markUsed(cardId: number) {
        const used = dayjs();
        const data = { id: cardId, dateUsed: used.toISOString() }

        try {
            fetch(`/api/card/${cardId}`, {
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                method: 'POST'
            }).then(() => {
                setAlert("Complete.", "success");
                // TODO: why is this necessary to refresh the ui?
                if (card !== null) { card.dateUsed = used.toDate() }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            setAlert("An error occurred while updating the record.", "error");
        }
    }

    return (
        <Container maxWidth='md' sx={{ paddingLeft: { xs: 0, sm: 0 }, paddingRight: { xs: 0, sm: 0 } }}>
            <MyAppBar title={deck.deckName}>
            </MyAppBar>
            <MuiCard key={card?.id || 0} sx={{
                paddingLeft: { xs: 2, sm: 5 }, paddingRight: { xs: 2, sm: 5 },
                minWidth: 275, minHeight: "40vh",
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}>
                <CardContent sx={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    flexFlow: 'column',
                    flexGrow: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                }}>
                    <Typography variant="h4" component="div" sx={{ flex: '0 1 auto' }}>
                        {card?.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 10, px: { sm: 4, md: 10 }, flex: '1 1 auto' }} variant="h5" component="div">
                        {card ? card.description : 'There are no cards in this deck.'}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography sx={{ marginTop: "auto", pt: 8, flex: '0 1 40px' }} color="text.secondary" >
                        {formatLastUsedDate(card?.dateUsed ?? '')}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions sx={{ marginTop: 'auto' }}>
                    <Button disabled={card === null}
                        onClick={e => {
                            setJustClicked(false);
                            router.push(`/card/pick?deck=${deck.id}`);
                        }}>
                        pick a random card from this deck
                    </Button>
                    <Button disabled={justClicked || card === null} onClick={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setJustClicked(true);
                        markUsed(card?.id ?? 0);
                    }} >mark as used</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </MuiCard>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default CardPage

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {

    // two options: either a specific card id passed, or else a deck id, 
    // from which we should randomly pick

    const dateBefore = dayjs().subtract(3, 'day').toDate();    // don't re-pick any items for three days

    // TODO: add a property for "don't pick again" to avoid the last ID picked

    let deckId = context.query.deck;
    let cardId = context.query.id;

    let deck: Deck | null = null;
    let card: Card | null = null;

    if (deckId !== undefined) {
        const filter = {
            where: {
                idDeck: Number(deckId),
                OR: [
                    { dateUsed: null },
                    { dateUsed: { lte: dateBefore } }
                ]
            }
        };

        // pick a random card
        const cardCount = await prisma.card.count({
            ...filter
        });

        // are there any cards within the date range?
        if (cardCount === 0) {
            // no: just pick *any* card from the deck
            card = await prisma.card.findFirst({
                where: {
                    idDeck: Number(deckId)
                }
            });
        } else {
            const skip = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardCount);
            card = await prisma.card.findFirst({
                skip: skip,
                ...filter
            });
        }
    }

    if (card === null && cardId !== '' && !Number.isNaN(Number(cardId))) {
        card = await prisma.card.findFirst({
            where: {
                id: Number(cardId)
            }
        });
    }

    if (card !== null) { deckId = card?.idDeck.toString() ?? '0'; }

    deck = await prisma.deck.findFirst({
        where: {
            id: Number(deckId)
        }
    }) || { id: 0, deckName: "None" } as Deck;

    return {
        props: {
            card: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(card)),   // TODO: research this prisma Date hack; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176573/object-object-object-cannot-be-serialized-as-json-please-only-return-js
            deck
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code for the `/card/[id]` page? Could you also add the code for the `Button` component?

Comment: Certainly. The `Button` is from material ui, but as I noted the error occurs even when I replace it with a `next/link`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` is missing a dependency array. Try this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
        router.push(`/card/${card?.id}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
  }, []);
```